# Render view to string outside controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to render a view from a class, which is not controller?

For example, I'm having a class which will return some data, like controls, which i want to derive from my view.

Is it possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

In a view, we have a method named Html.Partial which renders a partial to a string. Within your controller, you can instantiate an HtmlHelper instance and then call the Partial extension method on it. Make sure you import the System.Web.Mvc.Html namespace in your controller.

Comment: What an oddly accepted question.  Question: "render a view from a class, which is not controller?"  Answer: "Within your controller..."

Answer (score 4):

The open source Razor Engine does exactly what you need: https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine

```
string razorText = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(razorTemplateFileLocation);
string emailBody = Razor.Parse(razorText, yourViewModel);
```

Answer (score 3):

I did it using this:

[Rendering ASP.NET MVC Razor Views outside of MVC](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2013/Jul/15/Rendering-ASPNET-MVC-Razor-Views-outside-of-MVC-revisited)

Quite easy. You just need to add one class([ViewRenderer.cs](https://github.com/RickStrahl/WestwindToolkit/blob/master/Westwind.Web.Mvc/Utils/ViewRenderer.cs)) and it is ready to use.

For example, I can put this code outside Controller:

```
string html = ViewRenderer.RenderView($"~/Views/Partials/Email/WelcomeEmail.cshtml", viewModel);
```

Comment: I never thought about creating an empty controller to fake it out. Thanks for the idea!